# Generated Sources Root gone after every git pull in IntelliJ

Tags: java, git, maven, intellij-idea

One of the many modules I'm working on uses "generated-sources" for a couple auto-generated Java classes that the rest of the code depends on. Unfortunately, every single time I do a git pull it gets reset and I have to do mark the folder as "Generated Sources Root" again.

[image: Generated Sources Root]

It's not a deal breaker, but it's really annoying. Isn't there a way to automate this? I don't know, some setting in IntelliJ or perhaps even directly in the pom.xml?

Comment: How do you generate sources? Do you use some plugin?

Comment: As this is a generated folder have you considered putting this in the ignore list? That way git should not interfere with it.

Comment: I didn't write this auto-generation code, but it looks like it uses JAXB. The folders are already on gitignore, yet it still messes with them.

Comment: Seems it's not configured as generated sources root in pom.xml, so IDE doesn't mark it. IDEA uses pom.xml as an initial source of project configuration.

Comment: But it is, see the post below. IDEA seems to ignore that specific plugin execution goal.

Comment: This looks like a bug. Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with a sample project.

Comment: Make also sure to check with the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing | **Keep source and test folders on project reload** option enabled.

Answer (score 3):

You can give a try to [build-helper-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) and add more source directories to your project explicitly:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/...</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Also there is a little trick - actual source generation must happens before this goal execution.

In our project IDEA works pretty well with this approach.

Comment: This has always been in our project for this exact reason, but it seems to get ignored.

Comment: could you please check/confirm your sequence of maven goals execution? IDEA may ignore generated sources, if they are added later, than 'generate-sources' phase. also you can try to remove '.idea' folder/project. and create it from scratch. sometimes it also helps.

Comment: The builder-helper plugin is pretty much the very last thing in the pom. How can I trace the order of executed commands?

Comment: when you build your project all executions/goals/plugins are reported in maven output. just use text search for 'build-helper-maven-plugin' and your plugin for code generation.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `generated-sources` folder to git ignore file. Git ignore file if not already exists can be added in intelli idea like:
[image]

Then add `generated-sources` folder relative path like `generated-sources/`in git ignore file & commit .gitignore file. From next time any changes in that folder will not be overwritten or will be committed to server.